# Using Ptolemy's Theorem

Tags: geometry, circles

Let M be the midpoint of the arc $AB$ of some circle, and let $P$ be an arbitrary point on the same arc. Prove that $PA \cdot PB + PM^2 = MA^2$. [image]

This is the image that I was given with the hint being "Through $M$ draw a chord $MQ$ parallel to $AP$."

Any help would be appreciated on this problem !

Comment: Are you sure $Q$ isn't in the equation to be proved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $AP//MQ$ we know $APMQ$ is an isosceles trapezoid. This, and $AM = BM$, gives us $$\angle PQB = \angle PMQ = \angle AQM = \angle MBA = \angle MAB = \angle MPB$$
Hence we have $PM//BQ$, and hence $PMBQ$ is an isosceles trapezoid with $PB = MQ$. Therefore, from Ptolemy's Theorem in $APMQ$, $$MA^2 = PQ\cdot MA = PA\cdot MQ + PM \cdot AQ =  PA \cdot PB + PM\cdot AQ = PA\cdot PB + PM^2$$

Note: The first and last equality is because $APMQ$ is an isosceles trapezoid and hence $PQ = MA$ and $PM = AQ$, the second is from Ptolemy's inequality, the third is because $PB = MQ$ as stated above.